# Do I need to close unused prepared statements?

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I have developed some kind of a query builder and I have written some tests to check if the QueryBuilder builds correct queries.

So i have a set of self-written queries, which are the expected queries, the QueryBuilder shall produce.

In my opinion it is not enough to just compare these queries but also to test whether these queries are compiled by the underlying DBMS.

Hence, I am using `PDO::Prepare` (while EmulationMode=off!), to let the DBMS check my expected queries.

This PHPUnit Test is quite simple:

```
/**
 * @dataProvider provideExpectedSQLResults
 */
public function testExpectedSQLResults(string $sql)
{
    $this->getPdo()->prepare($sql);
}
```

This way i can even check if my QueryBuilder does (un)named parameters correctly.

Now my question:

**Do I have to "cleanup" all these opened prepared statements?**

Comment: PHP will do it for you each time the script terminates.

Comment: In plain PHP you get a PDOStatment object back to keep track of them.  So PHP as a whole doesn't do that for you.  So the answer is don't worry about them.

Comment: use should add that in `__destruct()` method `public function __destruct(){ $this->getPdo()->close() }`

Comment: I think you are confusing a prepared statement with an open database connection.  There is no such thing as a opened or closed prepared statement in PDO, I don't know what `My QueryBuilder` means...  But I can tell you in your `testExpectedSQLResults` method you won't be executing that query because you dont return the statement object from `PDO::prepare`

Comment: Once your statement handle/object is out of scope, PHPs garbage collector will kick in.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix: No, i am not confusing a prepared statement with an open db connection. My Question is pretty clear. The query is not executed, but parsed (because emulation mode = off), even when i am not using the returned statement in a parameter. I don't even want to execute it but to parse it.

Comment: i meant " returned statement in a _variable_" instead of "returned statement in a _paramenter_"

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments.

I think you are confusing an open database connection with a prepared statement.  For a prepared statement   PDO returns a PDOStatment object you need to call execute on.  In fact PDO doesnt even have an execute method.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php

Further there is no such thing as an open or closed prepared statement.

In your example code:

```
public function testExpectedSQLResults(string $sql)
{
    $this->getPdo()->prepare($sql);
}
```

This is essentially moot (unless you are just doing it to throw an exception, which is still mostly moot see below) as you can never execute this query because you don't return the PDOStatment object that actually has an execute method.

In the case of a DB connection, generally you wont have to worry about this either

For testing `PDO::prepare` does return a boolean false or throws an exception depending on how its setup.  Parametrized data doesn't exist (typically) in source code. It's dependent on the state of the application when its running.  The input data if you will.  Without this there is no way to really test it.

Basically what you are doing above is just going to test the syntax of your SQL, which typically will be good or bad and wont change much based on user input.  Even dynamic queries will either work or not, because your SQL is either going to be syntactically correct or not.  If it's not you will have to change the code that generates it, something you'll find out as you develop it.

Unit testing is a different matter, if you use something like **PHPUnit**.  Where you can use fixtures and mocking for input data etc..   This is more for testing your code against known use cases, so that if you make a code change here, you don't suddenly wind up with an error over there.  And so on.  This is something you could look into for this.  You didn't mention it in the question so I just assumed your not using it.

In PHPUnit you could test if this test method throws a particular exception for example like this using an annotation:

```
/**
 * @expectedException \PDOException
 */
```

https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.0/index.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hello, i limited my question to the essentials and i explained everything that is relevant for my question. your reference to PHPUnit is not relevant for my question and additionally does the total opposite of what i want.

Comment: Regarding "open"/"closed": I don't know the correct terms for that in english, but you definitely have a statement which is already parsed and where you only submit parameters on execution. this way it is "open", which should maybe only mean "prepared".